# Trouble Converting HTML to PDF

Tags: vb.net, itext

I'm using Itext Sharp and trying to convert my .aspx web page into a PDF.  I'm using Web Forms and programming in Visual Basic.  The web page itself is a table that holds a lot of data.  I want to take the table from the page and make it into a pdf.  The web page requires a variable, buildingID, to be passed in to correctly display the data in the table, so I tried to use Web Client to capture the current web page, but it gives me a 500 internal server error.  How do I capture the current web page so I can pass it into the String Reader?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
 Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
    Dim document As New Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30)
    Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms)

    document.Open()
    Dim wc As New WebClient()
    Dim url As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri

    Dim htmlText = wc.DownloadString(url) <----Error is here
    Response.Write(htmlText)
    Dim strreader As New StringReader(htmlText)

    Dim htmlarraylist As List(Of IElement) = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(strreader, Nothing)

    For i = 0 To htmlarraylist.Count
        document.Add(htmlarraylist(i))
    Next

    document.Close()
```

Comment: You don't need to get the get the get the get the... web page from itself. You just need to create the PDF from the data.

Comment: Additionally, please don't use the obsolete `HTMLWorker`. Use `XMLWorker` instead for existing iText-based projects, or iText 7 + pdfHTML for new development.